# Qualitative data analysis for statisticians?

Tags: references, qualitative

Occasionally in my professional work, I've run into the need to analyze qualitative data. Because of some assistance I've had from non-statistician colleagues, I've learned about techniques such as [thematic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_analysis) that I was never taught in my statistical coursework.

Are there any good references (preferably textbooks) that people recommend for statisticians who wish to learn qualitative research techniques? I have never seen a single statistics class which covers such material - such classes that seem to teach this material are primarily focused in the social sciences.

Comment: Maybe I have not seen the best of thematic analysis, but in the half-dozen cases I have seen it there was little more value than opinion wrapped up in technical babble.

Comment: You can have probability distributions over qualitative variables, although estimating them will require adequate sample sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In multivariate time series analysis, "statistical factors" (identified by empirical methods such as SVD or PCA) and "fundamental factors" (identified by a qualitative attribute such as company industry) are competing approaches to modeling multivariate data. The "factor analysis" chapter in Johnson and Wichern discusses rotating empirically defined factors to qualitative factors.

> Johnson, Richard Arnold, and Dean W. Wichern. *Applied multivariate statistical analysis.* Prentice Hall.

"Latent class analysis" combines qualitative and quantitative concepts, see the R package [poLCA](https://cran.r-project.org/package=poLCA) and related [article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i10/v42i10.pdf).

> Linzer, Drew A., and Jeffrey B. Lewis. "poLCA: An R package for polytomous variable latent class analysis." *Journal of Statistical Software* 42.10 (2011): 1-29.